# I cant shutdown or restart ubuntu with cinnamon

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, gui, cinnamon, restart

I recently installed Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04, now I can't shutdown or restart the system using the GUI, I must logout to do it.

I tried to shutdown and restart from the applet but nothing happens, I tried also to reinstall Cinnamon but the problem persists.

[image: picture]

Comment: Do you get the correct dialog when executing `gnome-session-quit --power-off`?

Comment: No ,i get the same dialog

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-log-out`?

Comment: i get false in the output

Comment: As intended. So this is not the issue.

Comment: so what can i do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33942/discussion-between-user3681546-and-the-seppi).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, my setup is Ubuntu 14.04 and Cinnamon 2.8.6

Here is how I solved it:

1. Install `dconf-tools`. Run in a terminal window:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor`:

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
3. Go to `org > cinnamon > desktop > session`
4. Change `session-manager-uses-logind` to `TRUE` (checked)
5. Logout and login
6. Now you'll have different options

[image: dconf-editor GUI]